# Can't get instagram search box using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I have been building an instagram bot using python and selenium. I am trying to get the search box element and run a search. However selenium can't seem to be able to detect the element. I have tried getting it by every method available (Xpath, css selector, etc).

Here is one of the ways I've tried searching for it (please note that I have also implemented time.sleep to give the page time to load).

```
def search():
DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/kiluas/selenium/driver/chromedriver'
webd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_PATH)
webd.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.LWmhU._0aCwM > input')
```

Here is the error log it spits out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autologinIg.py", line 80, in <module>
    loginInstagram('username', 'password', 3)
  File "autologinIg.py", line 45, in loginInstagram
    search()
  File "autologinIg.py", line 78, in search
    webd.find_element_by_css_selector('#react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.LWmhU._0aCwM > input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.LWmhU._0aCwM > input"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

Any idea what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Have you provided wait from before interacting the element?

Comment: Yes I have, as stated in the question. It still gives me an error unfortunately.

Comment: Are you getting any popup before interacting search box?

Comment: I am handling the popups that show up after logging in. I then go to the explore page(no popups there) and then run the search function.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the class names they vary in each run so that we cant automate
Your selector is:
#react-root > section > nav > **div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp** > div > div > div.LWmhU._0aCwM > input'

div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp - Is this remaining constant in your css selector?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case all the fields remain the same in every test I run.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to insert value in `searchbox`.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Search']"))).send_keys("text to be search")
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Please note** if you received any notification pop up you need to use below code before search.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click()
```